# identities other than $(a-b)^2=(a+b)^2-4ab$?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, trigonometry, diophantine-equations

We know that for any integer (or real in general) the following equation
$$
(a-b)^2=(a+b)^2-4ab
$$
 holds for all $a,b$.

I am looking for some other identities which involves $a+b$ and $ab$ and derive $a-b$ or similar relations.

Comment: Just raise both sides of this equation to any natural number power for infinitely many such identities.

Comment: $(a+b)^4-(a-b)^4=8ab\cdot((a-b)^2+2ab))$. You can come up with formulas like these for many powers of $a+b,\;a-b$.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity

Comment: Is there a question which you wan to solve

Comment: What has this to do with `complex-analysis`? Or `diophantine-equations`?

Comment: @PeterForeman, I need some identities which is not only by raising the power of both sides and manipulate them.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, sometimes using elementary complex analysis one can get nice relations. For instance "visual complex analysis" Tristan Needham.

Comment: Here's a suggestion to make your question more specific while maintaining the spirit (I hope): Is there a way to classify all polynomials $p(x,y,z)$ with integer coefficients in such that $p(a+b,a-b,ab)$ is identically zero? Then the examples raised by Peter will make up one classification, and the question is whether there are any more.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some example of $(a+b)^n-(a-b)^n$:

\begin{align*}
(a+b)^3-(a-b)^3 & = 2b(3a^2 + b^2), \\
(a+b)^4-(a-b)^4 & = 8ab(a^2+b^2),\\
(a+b)^5-(a-b)^5 & = 2b(5a^4 + 10a^2b^2 + b^4),\\
(a+b)^6-(a-b)^6 & =4ab(3a^2 + b^2)(a^2 + 3b^2) 
\end{align*}

Comment: thanks, but I do not need extra terms like $(a^2+...)$ etc. I like to have identities which include only some multiples of $a+b$, $ab$ and $a-b$

Comment: You can rewrite it, i.e., $(a+b)^4-(a-b)^4=8ab((a+b)^2-2ab))$ with only $ab,a+b,a-b$.